# Give read/read access to aws S3 to cognito users

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have a web app (Angular + back end using Spring).

When a TOTO user creates an account, I use Aws cognito for the creation of the account and the validation of his email.
              Once the account is validated, cognito sends me back the user's info (id + authentication token). I use this id to create this user in my back end.
              To access the APIs of the back end, I put in front of it a gateway API linked to cognito which checks the token and the identity of the user.

```
          The use case above works well and I managed to implement it.

          The problematic case is below:
```

Once in the app, TOTO has to create a company.
This company is a kind of merchant account, an organization, materialized in the back end by a name and an id. The user can create as many companies as he wants.
The company gathers contents. For example, I create a company called "Pokemon", everything I would do in the web application, upload from apk, upload images, etc... will be stored in an S3 bucket with the url /name-of-the-bucket-of-images/companyId/images/images.jpg. End users (other cognito users too) will be able to go to the non-admin part of the app and in Pokemon , see the images, apks, etc in this folder

I'd like to be able to do three things:
- Make the bucket private, that is, give read and write access only to the cognito user who created it...

```
          As a Toto user, I can add Tony (who is also a cognito user) in my company so that Tony can help me upload my images and administrate
```

- How can I do under AWS, to give read and write access to the S3 folder of this company to this user cognito TONY?

- How do I make it so that end users can have read access to this folder just to see the images and contents of this company?

I've been blocking on it for a few days now and I haven't been able to find an interesting answer on the internet. Knowing that I can control the creation of roles and others from the back end.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Cognito users can be part of one or more groups. Each of these groups can have an IAM role [assigned to it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html).

Whenever a user logs in an IAM Key, IAM Secret Key and Session key will be returned that can be used to interact with other AWS services.

In the policy you can refer to the `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub` value, to enhance your limitation of access to a specific "folder".

By ensuring all folder prefixes for the relevant S3 objects are created with a leading `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub` it will fulfil your requirements.

Additional information can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/).

Comment: The IAM details that `Auth.currentCredentials()` returns seems to always be limited to the identity pool's Authenticated Role setting. Even if I log in as a user who is a member of, say, an `administrators` group, and that group has its own IAM, I still only get the default Authenticated Role from the identity pool. How can I get a different role if I log in as an administrator vs any other user? Many thanks